# Having issue in learning CSS Grid and Flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having issues in learning CSS Grid and Flexbox I can not understand the layouts and understand tags. Is there a solution or a way to learn?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this grid learning game will help you https://cssgridgarden.com/

Answer (score 0):

Don't memorize codes, use what you will learn in practices, search about your questions.
you can write a documentation for yourself, draw divs (for example to see whats the difference between "align" and "justify" values).

Answer (score -1):

### Grid:

Grid Layout

> The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with rows and columns, making it easier to design web pages without having to use floats and positioning.

For more information try:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

---

### Flexbox:

CSS Flexbox Layout Module

> The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without using float or positioning.

For more information try:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Hope these help :)

Comment: Thabks for the feedback. Is what I edited good?